# How to make a dynamic form refresh itself after loading data from database

Tags: javascript, html

I have a modal dynamic form (edit user details) that changes the fields depending on the selected "Role" of the user.

I can successfully retrieve data from the database to the fields, but my problem is that upon loading the modal, it doesn't update the available fields in the form to fit the role_id that was retrieved from the database (although if I reselect the said role, it works).

How can I make the form automatically add / remove the fields to match the selected role_id?

HTML Form

```html
<form id="form-edit-account">
                 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                  <div class="container my-2">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Role</label>
                            <select type="select" id="update-role" class="form-control edit_role update-role" name="role_id" required>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group edit-student-number-container hidden">
                          <label>Student Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_student_number" name="student_number" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="edit-organization-container hidden">
                        <label>Organization Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_organization_name" name="organization_name" required>

                        </div>
```

JS for the update-role

```js
$(document).on('change', '#update-role', function() {
      var val = $(this).val();

      if(val != 3){
        $('.edit-student-number-container').show();
      }
      else {
        $('.edit-student-number-container').hide();
      }

      if(val != 1){
        $('.edit-organization-container').hide();
      }
      else {
        $('.edit-organization-container').show();
      }

    });
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Comment: my bad, I forgot to remove it. Edited